Site page shows error on production
When I clicked on Site page. It shows below error
Authorization Required

You must first log in or register before accessing this page.
If you have forgotten your password, click Forgot Password to reset it.

We need more information. Is this Site.com or Digital Experience? While they basically do the same thing, the solution is different for each.

That error message is the biggest red herring in the SF ecosystem.  It throws up that error when a page request causes an exception, generally in the Apex controller or a class called by the Apex controller.  So, it might have nothing to do with authorization.  Try the following....
Put on Salesforce Debug Logging.
Load the Page.  Take whatever action causes the error.
Look at the list of the recent Debug Logs.  The most recent log will be the Authorization error.  The second most recent log will be the log where the actual error occurred.
But, I think there are times when you might not get a Debug Log, like when for a VF page, there is an Exception in the constructor.  If there is only one log and it's for a VF page, you may have to hack with the  constructor code to figure out what's going on. Any maybe there really could be an authorization error but in my experience, it's almost always a fault in the process that tried to load the page.
Here is an article from SF on the behavior -- https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386094&type=1

An exception causes a "Under Maintenance" message, not "Authorization Required."

Not in my experience, but it could be a simply the way the site is configured as to which you get.

You're right. I wonder if I'm simply misremembering something else, or if it changed? Either way, I'll have to remember this one for the next time it inevitably comes up.

Please [edit] your existing answer rather than adding a second answer that is basically an extension of the first answer.

Thanks.  didn't know you could do that.  some forums disable edit after a very short period.

You're welcome! The [so] network of sites are different. Assuming you're not banned, you can always edit your own posts (questions and answers), and once you have sufficient reputation, you can even edit other posts as well. See privileges for things you'll be able to do as you gain reputation.
